# discord python multiple times snipes

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord python snipe bot but they only snipe once. I want it to be able to snipe multiple times. I want it do it with deque but I don't know how, as I'm new to Python.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
    
bot.sniped_messages = {}


@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    bot.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)

@bot.command()
async def snipe(ctx):
    try:
        contents, author, channel_name, time = bot.sniped_messages[ctx.guild.id]
        
    except:
        await ctx.channel.send("er is geen verwijderde bericht Dombo!")
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(description=contents, color=discord.Color.red(), timestamp=time)
    embed.set_author(name=f"{author.name}#{author.discriminator}", icon_url=author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Deleted in : #{channel_name}")

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I do not really understand your code. Please explain it a little more. Are you just trying to log messages that got deleted, and then you want to display it via command and decide how many messages are displayed?

Comment: like if someone send a message on my discord server and delete it i can do the command -snipe then it schows the message that is deleted but i want it that it can do more like -snipe 2 (second deleted message). so i want it that the bot can snipe multiple times. but yeah im new in learning so idk so much about it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to save all deleted messages:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(prefix="-")
sniped_messages = {}


@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    history = sniped_messages.get(message.guild.id, [])
    history.insert(0, message)
    sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = history

@bot.command()
async def snipe(ctx, position):
    try:
        message = sniped_message[ctx.guild.id][position-1]
        
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        await ctx.channel.send("er is geen verwijderde bericht Dombo!")
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=message.content,
        color=discord.Color.red(),
        timestamp=message.created_at
    )
    embed.set_author(name=f"{message.author}", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Deleted in : {message.channel}")

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

But I recommend that you create a `#logs` channel on your guild where your bot will send all deleted messages:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


MY_GUILD_ID = 623204625251827724
LOGS_CHANNEL_ID = 626136590305198113
bot = commands.Bot(prefix="-")


@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.guild.id != MY_GUILD_ID:
        return
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=message.content,
        color=discord.Color.red(),
        timestamp=message.created_at
    )
    embed.set_author(name=f"{message.author}", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Deleted in : {message.channel}")
    logs = bot.get_channel(LOGS_CHANNEL_ID)
    await logs.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```